# Durable Function switches back to Running state after completion

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable Function that always seems to be in a Running state. Even when it completed successfully.

It seems to complete, then it updates the `RunningStatus` back to `Running` for some reason.
This is the end of my logs:

```ini
[2021-07-22T08:52:59.211Z] Executing 'SavingsOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=36d509f3-4655-4382-9b72-ccb6fc39f413)
[2021-07-22T08:52:59.230Z] Executed 'SavingsOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=36d509f3-4655-4382-9b72-ccb6fc39f413, Duration=51ms)
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.206Z] SaveCustomerSavings stored 34 records.
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.210Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Function 'SavingsOrchestrator (Orchestrator)' awaited. IsReplay: False. State: Awaited. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.5.0. SequenceNumber: 24.
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.214Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Function 'SavingsOrchestrator (Orchestrator)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (null). State: Completed. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.5.0. SequenceNumber: 25. TaskEventId: -1
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.214Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Orchestration 'SavingsOrchestrator' awaited and scheduled 0 durable operation(s).
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.254Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Appended 3 new events to the history table in 35ms
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.290Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Updated Instances table and set the runtime status to 'Running'
[2021-07-22T08:53:02.292Z] Orechestrator_SaveCustomerSavings: Deleting [TaskCompleted#3] message from testhubname-control-00
```

What I basically do in my code is the following:

I start my `Orchestrator` (as a singleton):

```cs
await client.StartNewAsync<Task>("SavingsOrchestrator", _instanceId, null);
```

My Orchestrator function basically looks like this:

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SavingsOrchestrator))]
public async Task SavingsOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
{
    var a1 = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<MyModel>>("Activity1", null);
    if (a1?.Any() != true)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Run as 4 parallel tasks.
    var batchSize = a1.Count / 4 + 1;
    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    foreach (var batch in a1.Batch(batchSize))
    {
        tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<int>("Activity2", batch));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    var total = tasks.Sum(x => x.Result);

    logger.LogInformation($"Done: {total}");
}
```

Why is my Durable Function still in a Running state, even after it successfully ran?

### Update

In my code I do a "Fan out" by using a `Task.WhenAll`. When I remove that code and simply call `Activity2` in a single line, passing all the items to it instead of batches:

```cs
// Pass all items to the Activity function
var total = await context.CallActivityAsync<int>("Activity2", a1);
```

Then it updates the `RunningStatus` to `Completed`.

There seems to be an issue using `Task.WhenAll`. But I got this idea directly from the [Microsoft Documentation](http://context.CallActivityAsync%3Cint%3E(%22Activity2%22,%20batch))

Comment: It seems that orchestrator function execution is going to non-deterministic state. Read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints#orchestrator-code-constraints) and due to which it's going to infinite running state.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because there may be larger amount of data or return values get serialized into queue messages and [Azure storage queues only support 64 KB messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#capacity-and-quotas).

[image: Orchestrator Trigger]

For further information refer [Durable Function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/79)